# "nn" added before JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

In my application, I'm sending a HTTP request with JSON to get login details from a MYSQL database.

Just recently I've been trying to get the database and php api to run UTF-8 encoding.

However, when I try to login now, I get this error:

```
07-18 14:06:41.507: E/JSON(32162): nn{"tag":"login1","success":1,"error":0,"User":{"id":"1","email":"admin@fleetcoordinator.se","fullname":"Administrator","password":"admin","userRole":"Admin","userName":"admin"}}n

07-18 14:06:41.512: E/JSON Parser(32162): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value nn of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Obivously it's the "nn" before the JSON-data that is crashing the application, but where does this come from?

Php api:

```
// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);


    else if ($tag == "login1"){

    //request type is login1, for fltcoor db
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //check for user, fill it into user array
    $user = $db1->getLoginDetails($username, $password);
    if($user != false){
        //user found
        //put user details into JSON response array
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["User"]["id"]         = $user["id"];
        $response["User"]["email"]      = $user["email"];
        $response["User"]["fullname"]   = $user["fullname"];
        $response["User"]["password"]   = $user["password"];
        $response["User"]["userRole"]   = $user["userRole"];
        $response["User"]["userName"]   = $user["username"];
        //echo json response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        //user not found, echo json with error = 1(user not found)
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Wrong username or password";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Can anyone see where these "nn" are coming from. Please tell me if you need more information to track the problem.

Comment: Well, I added header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8'); when trying to encode the page in UTF-8, but it didn't work, so i removed it. 
This api has worked fine just before this without header('Content-type: application/json');, should i try to add it anyways?

Comment: I added header('Content-type: application/json'); still throws the same error though.
Just to be sure, you write the "header" line just after <?php right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by a missin "\" in my stringbuilder.

```
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        sb.append(line + "\n"); was sb.append(line + "n");, the \ was missing and adding 2 "nn" before the JSONObject.
```